# SonarQube SQL Azure Database support broken with 5.5?

Tags: azure, sonarqube, azure-sql-database, alm

I had an installation of SonarQube 5.4 running on Ubuntu (latest) against a SQL Azure database.
Since the upgrade to 5.5 it's not working anymore.
For the upgrade I deleted the data/es directory and updated the new conf file with my settings as advised.
The collation was wrong at first so I decided to try with a new db of collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.
Now it's looking for database_firewall_rules (table?) but cannot find it.
Any idea how I can solve that? Any table I could create?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're hitting a known bug in SonarQube 5.5: [SONAR-7589](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7589) . Until 5.5.1 or 5.6 gets [released](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/), you can temporarily use SonarQube 5.6-RC1 (available [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sonarqube/5.6/sonarqube/1yXW_wCLP8g/hbcTkol9FAAJ)).

Comment: thanks, installing those bits solved the issue indeed. Is it normal that with the RC I don't have any plugin available? (except the ones shipped with the bits)